# please help me with writing following spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to write something like this :

```
find where player id = ?1 && (lastspinneddate < ?2 || lastspinneddate == null)
```

, but when i am writing like this :

```
repo.findByPlayerIdAndLastSpinnedDateBeforeOrLastSpinnedDateIsNull(playerId,startOfDay);
```

, but this is not correct its returning like this :

```
find where (player id = ?1 && lastspinneddate < ?2) || lastspinneddate == null
```

Please help me with writing above spring data jpa, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you had a look into QueryDSL or Specification API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just annotate the method with something like

```
@Query("select p from Player p where p.id = ?1 && (p.lastSpinnedDate < ?2 or p.lastSpinnedDate is null)")
```

Comment: thanks for reply but can't we do without writing @Query, i want to know how powerful and flexible spring data jpa is?

Comment: Automatic query generation is fine for very simple cases. It's not supposed to avoid as many hand-crafted queries as possible. The horrible name of the method, in itself, is an indication that you should specify a query.

Comment: How to check for null inside @Query, its saying unexpected token "null"

Comment: My query missed an ending parenthesis. I fixed it. I have no idea if that's the problem with your query. Post it, and post the complete exception stack trace.